# How to watch a 1080p video on retina display with a 1:1 pixel ratio (with no scaling up)?

Tags: video, macbook-pro, display

I am trying to watch a 1080p video on my Macbook Retina 13 but it is scaled up to the 'scaled resolution' 1280x800. If the video is scaled down to 1280x800 before being displayed, I will be losing in precision.
VLC for example claims to support Retina Displays but that seems to only concern the fonts and not the video.

Comment: I believe that on a 2x Retina display, if you set the video to half size in VLC, you got a pixel to pixel resolution. You can verified that by taking a screenshot of a checker pattern video, like this one: https://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/641143-perfect-1-1-pixel-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't watch any full screen video that is not in the exact native display resolution without scaling. At least in my knowledge.

The question is - is the scaling good or not. You may try different players.

If you want pixel to pixel mapping, you can only set the player size to 100% of the video, and it'll show as one of the windows on the screen, depending on the video file resolution - but only that way will you have the pixel-accurate playback.

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can change scale option in System Preferences—›Displays. Maximum scaled down resolution for MBP Retina 13 is 1680x1050. It's not perfect solution — you still won't get accurate 1080p nor native 2560x1600, —  but it's definitely better than 1280x800.

[image: scale options]